# TypeORM One-To-One Relation: Entity column not found on either side?

Tags: typescript, typeorm, one-to-one

My postgreSQL DB contains three Entities:

```
@Entity()
export class User {

    constructor(email: string, displayname: string, passwordHash: string, salt: string) {
        this.email = email
        this.displayname = displayname;
        this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
        this.salt = salt;
    }

    @PrimaryColumn()
    email!: string;

    @Column()
    passwordHash!: string;

    @Column()
    displayname!: string;

    @Column()
    salt!: string;

    @OneToOne(type => Cafe, Cafe => Cafe.owner, {cascade: true})
    cafe!: Cafe;
}


@Entity()
export class Cafe {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    //TESTING
    @Column()
    name!: string;
    
    @OneToOne(type => User, User => User.cafe)
    owner!: User;

    @OneToOne(type => Gamestate, Gamestate => Gamestate.cafe, { cascade: ["insert", "remove", "soft-remove", "recover"] })
    gamestate!: Gamestate;
}


@Entity()
export class Gamestate {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    @Column()
    name!: string;

    @OneToOne(type => Cafe, Cafe => Cafe.gamestate)
    cafe!: Cafe;

    public update(): void {
        //TODO: do update Logic here
    }
}
```

When creating a user with cafe and gamestate filled, they are properly cascaded into the DB.
But when I try to find a Gamestate via

`const foundGamestate = await connection.getRepository(Gamestate).find({ where: { cafe: { name: "Test" } }});`

I get an error:

`EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column "cafe" was found.`

Even after trying to find a Cafe instead, the Error persists, so it seems like neither side actually has the One-To-One Relation?

`const foundCafe = await connection.getRepository(Cafe).find({ where: { gamestate: { name: "Test" } }});`

`EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column "gamestate" was found.`

Is my Entity setup wrong, or am I using find/where incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

### Update:

When using `find` method, typeorm does not allow adding where conditions on properties of related entities as of now.

There are 2 open issues to handle this behavior and once either of those is solved, the following answer would work:

Issues:

- [Allow WHERE clause on joined columns](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2707)
- [Finding entity with with relation condition](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4396)

---

You missed adding the required `@JoinColumn()` annotation on one side of your OneToOne relation. See [this article](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/one-to-one-relations.md) for more info.

Update your `Cafe` entity as below:

```js
@Entity()
export class Cafe {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    //TESTING
    @Column()
    name!: string;
    
    @OneToOne(type => User, user => user.cafe)
    @JoinColumn()
    owner!: User;

    @OneToOne(type => Gamestate, gamestate => gamestate.cafe, { cascade: ["insert", "remove", "soft-remove", "recover"] })
    @JoinColumn()
    gamestate!: Gamestate;
}
```

Then use the following syntax to query:

```js
const foundGamestate = await connection.getRepository(Gamestate).find({
    relations: ["cafe"],
    where: { cafe: { name: "Test" } }
});
```

Hope this helps you. Cheers !

Comment: I managed to do it via the query builder. Not ideal but at least it works: `const foundGamestate = await connection.getRepository(Gamestate).createQueryBuilder("gamestate").leftJoin("gamestate.cafe", "cafe").leftJoin("cafe.owner", "owner").where("owner.email = :email", {email:user.email}).getOne();`

Comment: No, with your query syntax I still get the original error. When searching for a Cafe instead, I always get undefined as result as soon as I include a subrelation in the where clause.

Comment: I searched and found that there are open issues (https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2707, https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4396) in typeorm to address this problem. So when it gets fixed (hopefully), you should be able to use the syntax I provided.

Answer (score 0):

This took me some time to figure.
The relation part on:
|

```js
return this.messageRepository.find({ relations: ['user', 'sender'] })
```

is the same name as the variable you define in entity, not the table name

```js
 @OneToOne(() => User)
    @JoinColumn({ name: "userId" })
    user: User;

    @OneToOne(() => User)
    @JoinColumn({ name: "senderId" })
    sender: User;
```